# Como puedo poner en color rojo los resultados de la tabla segun el estado NO ENTREGADO o ENTREGADO en color verde

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Necesitaria una ayuda con el siguiente codigo en PHP, lo que trataria de poner segun los resultados que vaya trayendo desde la base de datos del campo ESTADO, si me trae NO ENTREGADO quisiera poner el texto en ROJO y si me trae ENTREGADO quisiera poner el texto en VERDE.
hay alguna manera con PHP o JAVASCRIPT de hacerlo?

este es el codigo en PHP

```
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                    
                           <th>NUMERO</th>
                           <th>ESTADO</th>
                           <th>BORRAR</th> 
                         </tr>
                       </thead>
                <tbody>
            
                       <?php
                           $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM movimientos ORDER BY Id Desc");
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            ?>
                             <tr>
                        
                                <td><?php echo $row["Numero"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row["estado"]; ?></td>
                        
                               <td>
                            
                                    <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" 
                                        data-id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" 
                                        data-toggle="modal">
                                        <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                        title="Borrar"></i>
                                   </a>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                   <?php
                 }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

gracias por su lectura y comprension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guardas el resultado en una variable y la usas en el CSS. Algo así:

```
<?php
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM movimientos ORDER BY Id Desc");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
 $color = "red";
 if($row["estado"] == "ENTREGADO"){
   $color = "green";
 }

?>

<tr style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>">

//el resto del código
```

Me parece que ocupas bootstrap, así que tambien puedes ocupar las clases de alert

```
<?php
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM movimientos ORDER BY Id Desc");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 
 $color = "alert-danger";
 if($row["estado"] == "ENTREGADO"){
   $color = "alert-success";
 }

?>

<tr class="<?php echo $color; ?>">

//el resto del código
```

Comment: Perfecto crack....funciono...TE AGRADEZCO